# google oAuth for testing application

Tags: android, oauth

I just started studying android development few days ago.. so totally new.
I wanted to test the google API, specifically this project:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/tree/master/BasicRecordingApi

When I create the .apk and I try on my phone I get an error "Eception while connecting to Google Play services: null"

Through a search I found out that it can be because I didn't setup oAuth.

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-api-key

I don't have a developer account.
Do I need to sign up to be able to test the API?
Do I need to perform steps as it was my application that I am developing, also if I am just testing their app?

Thank you and sorry for the basic question..

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
https://console.developers.google.com/

and no I didn't need to register and pay just to test it for learning..

Comment: and also yes the error "Exception while connecting to Google Play services: null" was because I didn't setup the oAuth, now it works :P